# Am I guaranteed a unique positive integer solution to a linear system of $128$ variables, $2$ equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Background: So I was on a computer science problem, and I have an integer array of $128$ elements $\{a_0, a_1, ... , a_{127}\}$ where each elements must be an integer of value $\geq 0$.

We also know that integer has a valid range of$ -2^{31}$ to $2^{31} - 1$.

So Java calculates the hash value for the above array in closed form:

hash$1 = a_0 + 31a_1 + (31^2)a_2 + ... + (31^{127})a_{127}$

And suppose I generate another hash code with the same integer array:

hash$2 = a_0 + 17a_1 + (17^2)a_2 + ... + (17^{127})a_{127}$

Given the computed values of hash1, hash2, all the coefficients of $a_0, ..., a_{127}$,  and the additional requirement that all the unknowns $a_0, ..., a_{127}$ must be an integer of $ 0 \leq a\leq2^{31} - 1$, may I claim that there exist a unique solution for $a_0, ..., a_{127}$?

I do understand that a unique solution of a linear system requires 128 equations. However, will a1 >= 0, ..., a128 >= 128 help in this scenario?

Further, if I cannot claim the above, then what could be the alternate hash function that will uniquely identify each integer?

Thank you!

Comment: You may try quadratic programming. Write your linear equation as error function, something like (a0 + 31*a1 + (31^2)*a2 + ... + (31^127)*a127 -hash1)^2. Write the other linear equation also in the same way. Add them. Have your constrain equations and can try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: But with quadratic programming it is not necessary that you will get integer solutions

Comment: First off, $a_0$ is arbitrary, so no there is no unique solution.